# Laravel direct to index page having username

Tags: laravel

I want to redirect to index page having username or other things. Like a branch coordinator when do login , then he redirect to `index/{branch_name}`. 
Please help me to do that.

My Route :

```
 Route::get('/branch' , 'HomeController@index');
```

Controller :

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{  
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:branch');
    }

    public function index()
    {
         return view('branch.index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In web.php change to :

```
Route::get('/branch/{branch_name}' , 'HomeController@index');
```

In controller

```
 public function index($branch_name)
 {
   //$branch_name will be containg the variable
     return view('branch.index');
 }
```

To redirect to above page

```
return redirect()->route('branch/'.$branch_name);
```